'81 toyota battery being overcharged. Replacing voltage regulator did nothing
My 1981 Toyota pickup is showing around 15.3 volts while the engine is running. And after replacing the voltage regulator I have the same issue. I have cleaned every ground in the engine bay. The battery light is lit up on the dash. and the headlights don't work, there is a click from the relay when switching on the high beams(which also don't work). Not sure if it is related or not. Next thing I am going to do is clean the voltage regulator connector, and the cables on the alternator. Sorry if this isn't a place for automotive electrical issues. Im just trying to solve this because my car died in a parking lot a few days ago and I had to get a jump. Which confuses me because the battery isn't being undercharged. But it started up with a jump. Let me know what you think and thank you.

The 15.3 volts is what the alternator is producing (the battery alone wont give that). Step 1 is to get the battery checked at a service centre – The battery light is lit up on the dash. The headlight issue might be a fuse.
